# Android SDK manager not opening

Tags: 13.10, android, eclipse, sdk

I downloaded and installed the Android SDK ADT Bundle from the official website. When I want to start the SDK Manager a window appears:

> Initializing... the SDK manager will show up shortly
>   [image: the window that appears]

Then the window disappears and nothing happens. No error messages, nothing.
I tried also with installing eclipse and then adding the Android SDK, but the same thing happens.

Could someone help me?

I have Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

to make sure the SDK works by itself, open up terminal.
Then go to the sdk-directory/tools and run sdk manager by typing "./android".
If you see the similar thing you have right now, you must be missing some requirements like java. Read the section. Hope it helps you. :)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AndroidSDK#Setting_up_Java

Comment: I tried it but I got an error message that is too long to put in a comment.

Comment: can you tell me what exactly you tried? And you can paste the error message on online [link](http://pastebin.com)

Comment: Ok, here it is [link](http://pastebin.com/YC1ueJQ0)
I tried to run the SDK manager to run from terminal and I got this error message.

Comment: it seems like someone already had your problem, a quick search gave this link. It can be solved by making a symbolic link to the correct library path. Here, [eclipse swt libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165693/eclipse-cannot-load-swt-libraries). Pls let me know :)

Comment: Well. I tried it and the link was created. But it didn't worked. I searched for the link file in nautilus and I tried to open it. A messagebox appeared that said: "The link “libswt-*” is broken. Move it to Trash?" and
 "This link cannot be used because its target “/usr/lib/jni/libswt-*” doesn't exist." I checked and the folder /usr/lib/jni really didn't exist.
I hope you can find the answer.

Comment: Ah, no folder at all, meaning they aren't installed in the first place. So install those swt libraries by `sudo apt-get install libswt-gtk-3-jni libswt-gtk-3-java`. And try doing the symbolic link thing again. I love to help, don't worry.

Comment: Unfortunately still not working and I have no idea what the problem could be. I'm sure somehow it can be solved, but how?

Comment: Is java path set up correctly? `which java`. And is yr system 32 or 64 bits? If it's 64 bits, install 32 bit libraries too by `sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`. Let me know.

Comment: also install openjdk7 instead of 6

Comment: My system is 32 bits and I already have openjdk7. I executed the command which java in terminal and I got the following usr/bin/java.

Comment: hmm, that's mostly the checks I know. Just to be safe, install the libraries `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`. Then if it doesn't work, I found this on google `sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp`.

Comment: After i remounted it worked, it finally did.
Thanks a lot.